# CType in VB.NET with dynamic second parameter (type)

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting

In VB.NET CType can be used to convert one type to another.

```
CType(expression,type)
```

I have the "expression" stored in an instance object class, say `"objExp"`.
I have the "type" stored in an instance of Type class, say`"objType"`.

I am trying `CType(objExp, objType)`
I am getting compile error, how should I go about it ? "`objType`" is fetched and assigned at runtime.

Comment: `CType` is used to tell the compiler which type an object is, so  `expression` and `type` must be known **at compile time**. However, what error do you get at all?

Comment: And WHERE will you store the result if it's unknown until run-time? For this kind of conversion you can simply rely on **System.Convert.ChangeType**. Is this another XY problem?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, error is "Type 'objType' is not defined"

Answer (score 26):

Have you looked into the method [CTypeDynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.VISUALBASIC.CONVERSION.CTYPEDYNAMIC%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)()? The second parameter (ie: The Type) can be set dynamically. Great for when you are using Reflection.

For example:

```
CTypeDynamic(strValueToConvert, objTypeToConvertTo)
```

Comment: Well, for one reason, the return type of `CTypeDynamic` is `Object`, which is unfortunate but obviously unavoidable.

Comment: Maybe it's boxing and unboxing behind the scenes, but it seems to work.
Return CTypeDynamic(pString, GetType(T)) and my return type is the generic T.

Comment: Even better, generic on the CtypeDynamic
      Return CTypeDynamic(Of T)(pString)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not possible.  The `CType` expression must be passed a `Type` instance which is known at compile time like `Integer`, `String`, etc ...  It does not accept values which are of type `Type`

Comment: CTypeDynamic(Of T)(varA)